# How do I remove default Text Styles from the ribbon?

Tags: 2013, ribbon, style

I want to prevent our users from using the built in text styles. How do I hide or remove them from the ribbon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the elements from Ribbon.

Here is an article which explains how to find the ID and how to hide it

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2014/06/hide-from-sharepoint-ribbon/

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Styles {
    display:none;
}
```